# Openni in ROS ARM repository

Tags: robotic-arm, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to install ROS on Odrouid-U2 board. I used installation instructions from ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM

I was able to install core system, but some packages as openni_camera are marked as failed to build. There are also no libopenni and libopenni-sensor-primesense packages, which are provided in the ros repository for x86 architectures.

I was able to compile OpenNI and openni_camera from sources with minor modifications, so now I would like to look into why deb building process fails, but I don't know where to start.

Where I can find source code that is used for building these packages?
Is there any documentation about how is the packaging process organized?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61280/openni-in-ros-arm-repository/) by [Vladyslav Usenko](https://answers.ros.org/users/4660/vladyslav-usenko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running the ARM builds based on my fork of the build tools repository: https://github.com/trainman419/catkin-debs , and trying to push any fixes I make into the upstream repository where I can.

The OpenNI builds are missing for two reasons: I don't have builds of the driver packages you mentioned, and most of the reports are that the current OpenNI drivers run so poorly on most ARM chips that they're mostly useless, so getting them working hasn't been a priority.

The last build of openni-camera failed on Precise armel because the debs for drivers were missing: http://namniart.com/build/job/ros-groovy-openni-camera_binarydeb_precise_armhf/3/console ; I suspect my other targets are failing for the same reason.

If you can come up with ARM builds of the libopenni-dev and libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev debs, I'll inject them into my build system and retry the openni-camera builds.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vladyslav Usenko](https://answers.ros.org/users/4660/vladyslav-usenko/) on 2013-04-23**:
Looks like openni deb packages are coming from these repos: https://github.com/jspricke/debian-openni.git and https://github.com/jspricke/openni-sensor-primesense , at lease I haven't found any other repositories yet. They are not working out of box on arm, but I will try to patch them a little.

**Comment by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) on 2013-08-20**:
Has there been any progress on that?

**Comment by [Vladyslav Usenko](https://answers.ros.org/users/4660/vladyslav-usenko/) on 2013-08-20**:
I've managed to build the debs, but looks like the first version of openni doesn't work well on ARM. I ended up using OpenNI2. I think you can get CMake port from this repo https://github.com/jkammerl/OpenNI2/ and use it with catkin.